# How to keep authkey and users in sync for GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api, authentication

I'm trying to implement https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/authkey/index.html , it's working fine but I need to know how can I use either REST API or other type of automation flow so when new user is added, new authkey entry is added in file.
(I'm also open to store in PG if there is any way)